# How to import a JavaScript code to another html document?

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid, src

how can I import JavaScript document where defined some variables into a html document, so I can output these variables there?

I tried it that way but it didn´t work. I defined the variable title in my other script an gave it the Id title. The name of the file is server.js, so I worte in the html document this as the source but it doesn´t work. The data cell where I want to output it is empty. When I define the variable in the same document it works but not when i do it in the server.js document.

```
<body>
<script src="server.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<th>header</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> <div id="title"> </td>
</tr>

</table>

</body>
```

the part from my second script:

```
let title = $("#productTitle").text().replace(/\s\s+/g, "");
document.getElementById("title").innerHTML= title;
```

Comment: Variables declared with `let` do not end up in the global scope (the `window` object). Generally that is a very good thing, but if you really want to do that use `var` instead. Note that you're going to run into another problem, which is that your `<div id="title">` will collide with the variable anyway; that problem is in fact why avoiding the global scope is a great idea.

Comment: @Pointy Thank u very much! So I need to change the id or the name of the variable? They cant be the same? And would u recommend to wirte it all in one script because I always got told that one should wirte it in different scripts because it is clearer then?

Comment: Also the script runs before the document is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple. Just import the javascript file outside of the body tag. You are not getting the desired result because the JavaScript is loading before the remaining body elements and it is not able to find the desired element with id title.

Before putting the script tag just after `</body>` just open the browser console you will see an error like this: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')**.
So the new code should be like

```
<body> 
<table>
<tr>
<th>header</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> <div id="title"> </td>
</tr>

</table>

</body>
<script src="stack.js"></script>
```